# Difference between setxkbmap and localectl

Tags: setxkbmap

I'm a bit confused regarding the difference/relationship between `localectl` and `setxkbmap`. Is any of them meant to supersede the other? Or are they meant to be used in conjunction? Are they even changing the same settings?!

For instance here's my localectl output

```
--> localectl status
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: us
      X11 Layout: us
       X11 Model: pc105+inet
     X11 Options: terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
```

Which indicates that I only have the `us` layout, but in fact I have used setxkbmap to install another layout

```
--> setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105+inet
layout:     us,ar
variant:    ,mac
options:    grp:alt_shift_toggle,caps:escape,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
```

Answer (score 3):

`localect` changes the settings that should be used in programs (including Xorg server) started **after**, while `setxkbmap` changes keyboard options for the **currently running** Xorg server. Also `setxkbmap` allows more fine-grained control, and allows switching between varios layouts during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg/Keyboard_configuration):

> *setxkbmap* sets the keyboard layout for the **current X session only**, but **can be made persistent** in [xinitrc](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinit#xinitrc) or [xprofile](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xprofile). This overrides system-wide configuration specified following [Using X configuration files](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg/Keyboard_configuration#Using_X_configuration_files).

and

> For convenience, the tool *localectl* may be used instead of manually editing X configuration files. It will save the configuration in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf, this file should not be manually edited, because localectl will overwrite the changes on next start.

So `setxkbmap` overrides the configuration specified by `localectl`